# Storing an array of functions with parameters for execution later

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a feeling the following is a lack good design so if you can think of a better solution to my problem, please go ahead and tell me. I'm making a game with cocos2d and box2d for the iphone.

I have an array with 1000 CGPoints that represent straight line segments that make up a section of randomly drawn terrain. The ground is drawn one screen width behind and in front of the main characters position and its position is checked every game step.

I have multiple box2d objects that need to be created at points along the terrain (based on the characters position).

**Question:**

How can I store multiple references to functions to create objects, including parameters, which can be executed once my character reaches a certain position.

**More Info:**

Basically in my game, I create the game world a fixed distance infront of and behind my character in order to save computation. I have managed this with terrain but want to apply the same concept to in game items such as enemies, bridges etc. These will all be box2d bodies so I am trying to determine a way to store a list of upcoming box2d bodies (with positions at which they are created) and looping over these every game step in order for them to be created at the correct location ahead of the character.

Comment: what if you create an event? I guess you have a place where you check always where the character is, so maybe you can call it there:-? If not try to make a method that it's called each time your character is moving.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [`NSInvocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsinvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object to store a complete prototype method invocation (target, selector, and parameters). You can call the method at some point in the future with `-invoke` and fetch the return value with `-getReturnValue:`.

Comment: +1 good answer. But all things considered, there's probably a safer way of approaching the problem.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand from the question exactly what he's trying to solve, but I don't think there's anything inherently unsafe about using `NSInvocation`.

Comment: Not in `NSInvocation` itself, but storing a bunch of function pointers that can change depending on state (as the OP wanted) doesn't seem like such a good idea to me. But then again, I don't have a better one.

Comment: Basically, at the start of the game I create all 1000 ground points, but obviously I don't want to draw them all so I draw in front of and behind my main character by a fixed amount. I want to do the same for box2d game items but I need to store references to them somehow. I'll check out NSInvocation now.

Comment: There are definitely better solutions. It sounds to me like you would do better by using the factory design pattern and frequently checking if a new game item should be created just outside the screen. You don't need to create them up-front especially if their appearance is random. If it's not random, you only need the position  and type of each item, and then create it in due time. Use a controller-like class to handle all the conditions that lead to creation of new items.